# why do you copy the SQLite DB before using it?

Tags: sqlite

Everything I have read so far, it seems as though you copy the DB from assets to a "working directory" before it is used. If I have an existing SQLite DB I put it in assets.  Then I have to copy it before it is used.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Can you quote some source you found that idea from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your ideas.

I think what I might have figured out is that the install cannot put a DB directly to the /data directory.

In Eclipse there is no /data which is where most of the discussions I have read say to put it.

This is one of the several I found:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/comment-page-4/#comment-37008

Answer (score 1):

I can see a possible application to that, where one doesn't want to accidentally corrupt database during write. But in that case, one would have to move database back when it's done working on it, otherwise, next time program is run will start from "default" database state.

That might be another use case - you might always want to start program execution with known data state. Previous state might be set from external application.